# PHP Regex to remove non-related content but leave content within blocks

Tags: php, regex, tags

I need help to fix my regex, say if there is text like:

```
bla bla [bla1]something[/bla1] bla bla [bla2]something else[/bla2] bla bla bla
```

I want everything in bla1 and bla2 removed, including those tags. Can someone help me?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you building a BBCode parser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need is just to remove tags, then try:

```
$str = 'bla bla [bla1]something[/bla1] bla bla [bla2]something else[/bla2] bla bla bla';

$result = preg_replace('~\[([^\]]+)\].*?\[/\\1\]~', '', $str);

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: @prx: if my answer was useful - you're free to check it then ;-P

Answer (score 0):

Use regex:

```
\[bla1\]\s*(((?!\[bla1\]|\[/bla1\]).)+)\s*\[/bla1\]
```

to get everythign between bla1 and bla2, and then you can remove it

Comment: not just bla1 or bla2 it can be anything in those [something]something[/something]

Answer (score 0):

you don't need regex for that... I would use strpos, explode and substr for that functionality.
further reading:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

for example:

replace "[bla]" and [/bla] for ~bla~ and than explode on ~bla~.